# htaccess redirect index.php?p=my topic title to /my-topic-title

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting, seo

I'd like to use htaccess to change  my URL for my website

```
URL currently: example.com/index.php?p=my-topic-title
I want to be like : example.com/my-topic-title
```

my currrent htaccess file :

```
    RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^p/([0-9أ-يa-zA-Z_.]+) index.php?p=$1 [NC,L]
```

the result for this code is:

`example.com/p/my-topic-title`

I want url to be (without **(/p/)** ) like `:example.com/my-topic-title`

Comment: Your code suggests your current URL is `/p/my topic title`, not `/index.php?p=my topic title` (that would be the underlying filesystem path). The "result" for that code is `/index.php?p=my topic title`, not `/p/my topic title`? If you want to change the URL in your application to remove spaces, then you need to change this in your application, not in `.htaccess`. Or have you already done that and this is only for the benefit of SEO?

Comment: thanks i get the solution for (spaceses)
ok but i want to change my url (example.com/index.php?=my-topic-title ) to (example.com/my-topic-title )

Answer (score 0):

> I get the solution for (spaces) ok but I want to change my URL (`example.com/index.php?=my-topic-title`) to (`example.com/my-topic-title`)

I assuming you have already changed the URL in your application and you only need to *redirect* search engines/users in order to preserve SEO.

In which case, you can do something like the following *before* the above rewrite:

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=([^&]{3,})
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%1 [QSD,R,L]
```

This assumes the page title is at least 3 characters. The `%1` backreference contains the captured subpattern in the preceding *CondPattern*. The `QSD` flag (Apache 2.4+) is necessary to remove the query string from the redirected URL.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I solved it with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(([A-Za-z0-9]+[-]+[A-Za-z0-9]+)+[/])$  index.php?p=$1    [NC,L]    
# Handle blog requests
RewriteRule ^c/(([A-Za-z0-9]+[-]+[A-Za-z0-9]+)+[/])$  index.php?c=$1   [NC,L]
# Handle blog requests
```